# Kafka error handling and deadletter queues

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, spring-cloud-stream

Can someone help me understand why we need the deadletter queue mechanism when we have kafka consumer offsets to our rescue . If i receive a message in my kafka consumer , and i can always choose to commit my offsets . So if some failure happens , for example: if consumer shuts down while processing a message , the offset commit ( which happens in code ) is not performed and when consumer comes back up again it reads from the last position . Isn't this enough to keep things simple . Why do we need to enable DLQ and route failed messages to DLQ , is there any added advantage or am i missing something important ? By having a DLQ i have to write code to send messages from DLQ to the main topic thus complicating things

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you commit offset N, next time you consume you will start fetching at N+1. You don't have the granularity to commit each message individually.

In other words, if you've got 10 messages in your queue, and N=5 fails to be processed, you are unable to say that you have processed any message after 5 if you want to be able to consume 5 again in the future.

So the problem is when only a few messages fail to be processed, these are the ones that you send to the DLQ.

Comment: Hello , i dont think i understand it well . Kafka consumers do give the granular control over committing offsets per message . Please refer the offset management section over here . https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/clients/consumer.html . Which means i have message M1,M2 ,M3,M4 ,M5,M6 messages in a single partition and those are at offsets O1,O2,O3,O4,O5,O6 respectively , after reading M1 i commit O1 , M2 - O2 and so on ,while processing M5 , error happened so O5 commit did not happen , when the consumer is online it reads from O5 again . Please confirm why DLQ is needed in this case

Comment: Yeah, you are right. But then you are stuck processing M5 forever. It is common to keep processing the following messages and look at the ones that failed in the future by getting them from the DLQ (otherwise you are not processing anything at all until you fix the code to be able to process M5 or skip it somehow). In the case you expose, if your use case can work like that, then you don't need a DQL.

Comment: Thanks Gerard , that answers my question .

Answer (score 0):

Kafka picks up in batches from source topic for processing, event though you can put the batch size as one, it is never recommended due to poor performance.

So think of a situation where your batch size is 10 and its processing one by one and a false event (yes, of course you can avoid bad data by strict schema definition, but in real-world things can break) in this batch can throw some exception in application logic. So when consumer is back after crash and since there was no commit for current batch, it polls the same set again and this loops continue. So DLQ gives us an option to route the error ones to another topic which really needs to be inspected later than blocking the entire system due to "one" bad message.

Any events in the DLQ needs to be inspected in logs to identify the failure of the event. Mostly these are the edge conditions or a bug in our existing system.

Its not easy to skip an event from a topic even using admin tools in Kafka Broker. Its a very administrative overkill for ops/teams if you really run into a crash loop in higher env. So best option is to have a DLQ always where ever we have an option for it.

Comment: Thank you , does that mean while using spring cloud stream kafka binders and @StreamListener , although am getting only one message in by listener , behind the scenes , batching is happening , and if i do a manual commit , it would apply to the whole batch ?